# Limit Proof, Absolute Value

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$$x_n$ = $c$. Prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $|x_n|$ = $|c|$.

My gut tells me the triangle inequality is what I need to use, but I can't seem to reason it out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the reverse triangular inequality http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality:
$$
||x_n|-|c||\leq |x_n-c|.
$$

And then the squeeze theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry could you elaborate on how the squeeze theorem might follow from here?

Comment: By assumption, $\lim x_n=c$, ie $\lim (x_n-c)=0$ ie $\lim |x_n-c|=0$. So the rhs tends to $0$, and the lhs is bounded below by $0$. Squeeze indeed.

Comment: oh, great thanks, i think I follow you now

Comment: ah yes, fully clear to me now. Much appreciated!

Comment: @PaulGerard Great, then.